Is Apache Flink StateFun still supported and will it be updated for Flink 1.18?
I am using Apache Flink and the Stateful Functions (StateFun). I noticed there have been no contributions to the StateFun repository on GitHub for over a year. Can anyone confirm if StateFun is still supported and whether it will be updated to be compatible with Flink 1.18?
